# Can KieContainer load multiple packages? and what's the relationship between KieContainer and KieBase

Tags: drools

I'm new to drools. 
The project has several Kjars which are built from Kie workbench. And in our program, we want to put all these Kjars into one KieContainer. 
But I can see from the document is when creating KieContainer, it need a releaseId as parameter. The parameter is GroupId/ArtifactId/version of the Kjar, meaning, the KieContainer is related to only 1 Kjar.

So how can I load these Jars to only one KieContainer? or it is impossbile to load several Kjars into one container?

Another confusion is what's the exact relationship between KieContainer and KieBase?

Really appreciate in advance to answer my problem.

Answer (score 3):

First, I know you only asked about KieContainer and KieBase, but I think it's important to know about all 5 KieConcepts to get a full picture:

1. **KieServices**: allows you to create *KieContainers*.
2. **KieContainer**: has references to all rules, functions, etc.   A *KieContainer* can load a *KieModule* and its dependencies.  A *KieContainer* can have 1 or more *KieBases*
3. **KieModule**: Defines multiple *KieBases* and *KieSessions*.  *KieModules* can include other *KieModules*.  This means you can have a top level *KieModule* that contains assets from different domains.  Here is a link to the [schema for *KieModule*](https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-knowledge/blob/master/kie-api/src/main/resources/org/kie/api/kmodule.xsd), showing all the options you can have.
4. **KieBase**: represents a compiled version of a set of assets.  You can have a Stateless and Stateful session with the same rules for example.  Another option is to have one *KieBase* for one set of packages, and another *KieBase* for another set of packages.
5. **KieSession**: represents an instance of the rule engine containing the rules in a *KieBase*. Each *KieBase* can have one or more *KieSessions*

To my knowledge it is not possible to load several different Kjars into one KieContainer.

So my recommendation would be to either

A) Find a way to combine everything in one Kjar so you can create a
   KieContainer with all of your assets. This [documentation](http://planet.jboss.org/post/configuration_and_convention_based_building_and_utilization) may help you understand if this is a valid option for you given your use case.

B) Create a new KieContainer for
   each version of the assets that you need and route accordingly based on input.  This has a bigger memory footprint, but this may be the best option if you can't use a single Kjar.

Comment: What about KieRepository, what role does KieRepository play amony them?

Comment: In my use case, we have many different rule files from different vendors(with different packages),  we want to load them all togather into one KieContainer, and execute them against the same fact object with multiple threads, do we have to make a KieSession for each thread, or share one session among threads?